# c# writing x's using a loop

Tags: c#, loops

i have made textbox 1 and 2 to create a row of x's starting with one x, then enter and then xx and so on..

now i need textbox 3 and 4 to display the same but it has to do it beginning from 10 x's.
this is what i have:

```
namespace Vierkant
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string x = "X";

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if ( i == 0)
                {
                    x = "X";
                }
                else
                {
                    x += "X";
                }
                txt_box1.Text += (x) + "\n";
                txt_box2.Text += (x) + "\n";
            }
            for (int j = 10; j > 0; j--)
            {


                if (j == 10)
                {
                    x = x.Remove(x.Length - 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    x = x.Remove(x.Length - 1);
                }
                txt_box3.Text += (x) + "\n";    
                txt_box4.Text += (x) + "\n"; 

// txt_box4.Text displays correct but starts from 9 x's?

            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: @valverij really, printing a triangle of X's as interview question. Very strange.

Comment: Just a little something my teacher asked me to do, however i olmost had it and i could not find the final solution...

Comment: It is pretty hard as a new guy and help was allowed, but only as a last solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing one of the x's before displaying it.

```
if (j == 10)
{
    x = x.Remove(x.Length - 1);
}
```

Perhaps a better solution would be:

```
if (j < 10)
{
    x = x.Remove(x.Length - 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that solution just displays 10 x's in every row.
Thanks to your i < 10 i did create the solution :D


                if (j < 10)
                {
                    x = x.Remove(x.Length - 1);
                }
                else if (j < 9)
                {
                    x = x.Remove(x.Length - 1);
                }
                txt_box3.Text += (x) + "\n";
                txt_box4.Text += (x) + "\n";

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
private void button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int i;
    string allLines = "";
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        allLines += new string('X', i) + (i < 10 ? "\n" : "");
    txt_box1.Text = allLines;
    txt_box2.Text = allLines;

    allLines = "";
    while (--i > 0)
        allLines += new string('X', i) + (i > 1 ? "\n" : "");
    txt_box3.Text = allLines;
    txt_box4.Text = allLines;
}
```

This way is much clearer and more efficient, you are creating MUCH LESS strings in memory.